# How to order a page with items in JSP

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring, jsp

I must order a list of products based on price or name, ascending or descending.
The back-end is done, I only need to send a parameter saying which option was chosen from a list of dropdowns.

```
<!-- Dropdown for ORDER -->
<label for="order" class="control-label">Order by</label>
<select class="form-control" name="order" id="order"  onchange="...">
    <option value="priceAsc" selected>Price: lowest first</option>
    <option value="priceDesc">Price: highest first</option>
    <option value="nameAsc">A - Z</option>
    <option value="nameDesc">Z - A</option>
</select>
```

At `onchange`, I've tried different things like `onchange="location=location + '/order/'+ this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;"` and in controller I mapped the `/order/{orderBy}"` link.
The problem with this method was that once I clicked on one item, the link would become `/products/order/option_here`, and when I'd click again, `/order/option_here` would be added again at the end of the link, resulting `/products/order/option_here/order/option_here`

I also tried to get the value of `order` in `RequestMethod.GET`, but did not work (I believe because the page constructs after the `GET` method is finished)

The page which I'm trying to sort is called `/products`, so how can I sort it out, once the user has selected his option?

This is my method mapped in `@Controller`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/order/{orderBy}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView sortPageBy(@PathVariable String orderBy){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("viewProducts");
    List<Product> sortedProducts = productService.orderProducts(orderBy);

    modelAndView.addObject("products", sortedProducts);

    return modelAndView;
}
```

We are not allowed to use jQuery.

Comment: why you aren't allowed to use jQuery !! the easiest approach is to get the parameter orederBy in client side and send it over Ajax to your controller and then get the list of products !! i see that you're kind of complicating things there .

Comment: I don't make the rules ... only follow them :\

Comment: Where do you want to sort it? In the controller?!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `location` always "evaluates" to the current url, that is because the url always increase.
In your case it would be best to map the order as a request parameter.

for example

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/product", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView sortPageBy(
    @RequestParam("order") String orderBy){
      . . .
}
```

and the just call onSubmit in the onchange event

Comment: It does not work, I get `HTTP Status 400` saying that string `order` is missing

Comment: Can you check if the browser actually sumbit the order parameter ?
The request url should be something like `http://_yourhost_/products?order=priceAsc`

Comment: that's why I do not know what to do
I am looking for a way to implement that